# Woocommerce backend tax display

Tags: woocommerce, backend, tax

I building a Woocommerce shop.
By default the prices on the backend products page are shown without TAX.
The customer wants to show this price including the TAX.

Is it possible to change this?

Comment: I see the problem now.
It saves the tax settings from the moment you created the product.
This is a bit of a problem for me because i migrated all the products from OSCommerce.

Comment: You can make a direct SQL query on database product prices, making the prices without taxes. You should need to empty some related caches also… You should [search in those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D%5Bmysql%5D+product+price) for some tracks…